# Displaying a programs output in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, io

What view would be the best view for displaying text from the console? In particular output of a C program? For example if I used `system("gcc foo.c");` in my program and then wanted to display the output of that what view would a I use and how would I display it? Also, how would I get input too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to have a look at the [NSTask](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class. It allows you to call external programs, and then read and write to them using [NSPipe](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPipe_Class/Reference/Reference.html)s.

Comment: Will do! Exactly what I need! Thnx.